# Can I make C++ programs for BlackBerry (examples?)

Tags: c++, blackberry

Does anyone know I a can make C++ programs for the Blackberry platform?

In some old video they state that 3rd party applications can only be written in Java. Is this true. Or is it possible to write C++ applications if you flash the device?

If anyone has an hello world example in C++ for Blacberry please forward it.

/Thanks :-)

Answer (score 11):

There is a C++ SDK for Blackberry, but only for the older "three digit" models (ie 957 or before). To write for modern BB devices, you have to use the Java SDK.

Comment: +1 this.  If you're going to do mobile development for the mass market, iPhone aside, you'll want to do Java.  J2ME has a LOT going for it in terms of market penetration and features available via JSRs.